# Change Eclipse EMF EAttribute Value

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-gmf

I have an EAttribute in a class.
I need its value to be set from another java code in the EMF model rather than just typing it in the properties.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Set it as *derived*, generate the model code and then implement the missing corresponding getter.